# CUSP host function parallelization with openMP

Tags: cusp-library

Is the CUSP host function also implemented in parallel with openMP?
I am a bit confused since in the github discussion it says "added functionality in openMP" but there is no clear statement in the cusp that it is fully implemented with openMP.

Answer (score 1):

CUSP is built on [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust).

Thrust can take advantage of OpenMP, for example [as a device backend](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Device-Backends).  Thrust now also has the ability to re-target the host backend as well.

This means that if you properly selected the thrust  OMP backend, say for device activities, I think cusp should respect this and perform "device" operations on the host using OMP.